# MVC Azure SendGrid

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, sendgrid

I have a controller action method when triggered post data to the  ForgotPassword method:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
            {
                // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
            }

            string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", "Please reset your password by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");
            return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);

    }
```

web.config file

```
    <appSettings>
      <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
      <add key="SendGridUsername" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
      <add key="SendGridPassword" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
      <add key="SendGridApiKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    </appSettings>
```

My IdentityConfig file looks like this:

```
 public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        await configSendGridasync(message);
    }

    // Use NuGet to install SendGrid (Basic C# client lib) 
    private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
        myMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(
                            "Joe@contoso.com", "Joe S.");
        myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        myMessage.Text = message.Body;
        myMessage.Html = message.Body;

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridUsername"],
                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridPassword"]
                   );

        // Create a Web transport for sending email.
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

        // Send the email.
        if (transportWeb != null)
        {
            await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport.");
            await Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

}
```

However no email is sent , what am I doing wrong and  how can I  fix  this as I have followed the instructions  from Rick  Andersons post on msdn.

Comment: are you getting any error ? Can you please show us stack trace please

Comment: No  errors it is as if the email is  sent and when I check sendGrid website dashboard email sent is 0

Comment: Can you show us the response you are getting.

Comment: There is  no error  messages

Comment: Could be a configuration issue from SendGrid.

Comment: @user2713535 you should never expose your API key and credentials , I have masked them

Comment: @user2713535 check my answer you are following an old version

Comment: Can you confirm in your `IdentityConfig.cs` file that there is the line: `manager.EmailService = new EmailService();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an outdated version of sendgrid C# SDK which points to V2 api. The current API version is V3. The document which you are following is not updated . I am currently in progress to update the document. You need to add the below namespace in your service -

```
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail; //optional if you want to use the MailHelper class
```

And then use below code in your `configSendGridasync` method -

```
private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var apiKey = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridApiKey"]);
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        myMessage.AddTo(new EmailAddress(message.Destination));
        myMessage.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("Joe@contoso.com", "Joe S."));
        myMessage.SetSubject(message.Subject);
        myMessage.AddContent(MimeType.Text, message.Body);
        myMessage.AddContent(MimeType.Html, message.Body);
          try
           {
              var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
           }
           catch(Exception err)
           {

            Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport: ."+err.message);
            await Task.FromResult(0);
          }  
    }
```

You need to install Sendgrid package from nuget using the below command before writing the code -

```
Install-Package Sendgrid -Version 9.10.0
```

The full code is like below -

```
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

 public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        await configSendGridasync(message);
    }

    // Use NuGet to install SendGrid (Basic C# client lib) 
    private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            var apiKey = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridApiKey"]);
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
            myMessage.AddTo(new EmailAddress(message.Destination));
            myMessage.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("Joe@contoso.com", "Joe S."));
            myMessage.SetSubject(message.Subject);
            myMessage.AddContent(MimeType.Text, message.Body);
            myMessage.AddContent(MimeType.Html, message.Body);
              try
               {
                  var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
               }
               catch(Exception err)
               {

                Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport: ."+err.message);
                await Task.FromResult(0);
              }  
        }

}
```

Here is a link to example code :

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/USE_CASES.md

Comment: I have not received any email. Please  confirm what  should I contain in my webconfig

Comment: @user2713535 you only need the API key for V3 api

Comment: <add key="SendGridApiKey" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />

Comment: @user2713535 also `EmailAddress` class is not from `System.Net.Mail` it's from `Sendgrid`

Comment: How would it be possible in this case for the email not to be  delivered?

Comment: I had also upgraded the NuGet Package  some time back. It deleted the  assembly system.web.pages

Comment: @user2713535 have you debug what is the value of `message.Destination` in `configSendGridasync`

Comment: I played around with the code and Rick Andersons post. @Nadir thanks for the new answer it does work.